# Dynamically change element position depending on screen size

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

Here is a snippet of my code (from `asp.net mvc` web app):

```
<div class="jumbotron" style="margin-top: 20px; margin-bottom: -25px">
    <div class="row" style="margin-left: 0px; margin-top: -50px; margin-bottom: 20px">
<h2>ipsum lorem</h2>
</div>

<div class="row row-eq-height">
    <div class="col-md-3" style="vertical-align: top;">
        <a href="@Url.Action("Index", "ApplicationForm")" 
         class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" style="width: 200px; margin-top: 8px">Full</a>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-9" style="vertical-align: top;">
        <div style="font-weight: bold">ipsum lorem</div>
        ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum 
        lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem
    </div>
</div>
```

It displays a link as a button and a description and I've got 4 of them. My problem is that when the screen is smaller i.e. Mobile, it displays the description as one big skinny column.

I'd like to change that and display it below the button. Is there a way to achieve that using `CSS` or `Bootstrap`?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding you correctly, you could do something like this:

```
<div class="row row-eq-height">
  <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-12 col-xs-12" style="vertical-align: top;">
    <a href="@Url.Action("Index", "ApplicationForm")" 
     class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" style="width: 200px; margin-top: 8px">Full</a>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-9 col-sm-12 col-xs-12" style="vertical-align: top;">
    <div style="font-weight: bold">ipsum lorem</div>
    ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum 
    lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem
  </div>
</div>
```